# Send PHP cURL Request to QR API with multipart/form-data that includes several content-types and inputs with file upload

Tags: php, api, multipartform-data, php-curl

Language: PHP

Related Links:

[RapidApi](https://rapidapi.com/linqr-linqr-default/api/qrcode3)

[Linqr](https://linqr.app/docs)

Problem: Unable to figure out how to post to API with several content types in a multipart/form-data PHP cURL request.

I am trying to reproduce the functionality of [Linqr](https://linqr.app/) in my own project with the added feature of batch QR production.

I'm currently able to create a custom single QR with custom image if the image file is already hosted on a URL.

I'm struggling to figure out how to POST the entire form including the user choices for the QR AND an uploaded file for the logo.

How do I access the logo file information when a user uploads to the document and then add that to my code to post to the API so it returns the full custom QR with the user uploaded image?

I've tried using the following but it only displays two arrays of 'items' and 'output' without being able to access the nested arrays.

Also, I'm completely lost on how to get the uploaded image to post at the same time of the other information.

Based off this post: [GIST](https://gist.github.com/maxivak/18fcac476a2f4ea02e5f80b303811d5f)

PHP File:

```
<?php
header("Location: home.php");

// data fields for POST request

$postFields = array(

  'items'=> array(
      'image' => array(
          'uri' => $logo,
          'modules' => true
      ),
      'data' => $qrUrl,
      'style' => array(
          'module' => array(
              'color' => 'black',
              'shape' => 'default'
          ),
          'inner_eye' => array(
              'shape' => 'default'
          ),
          'outer_eye' => array(
              'shape' => 'default'
          ),
          'background' => array()
      ),
      'size' => array(
          'width' => 200,
          'quite_zone' => 4,
          'error_correction' => 'M'
      ),
      'output' => array(
          'filename' => 'qrcode',
          'format' => 'png'
      )
  ),
  'output' => array(
      'filename' => 'qrcodes',
      'format' => 'zip'
  )

);

// files to upload
$filenames = $_FILES['logoUpload']['tmp_name'];

$files = array();
foreach ($filenames as $f){
   $files[$f] = file_get_contents($f);
}

// URL to upload to
$url = "urltouploadto";

$curl = curl_init();

$url_data = http_build_query($postFields);

$boundary = 011000010111000001101001;
$delimiter = '-----' . $boundary;

$post_data = build_data_files($boundary, $postFields, $files);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($post_data);
echo "</pre>";

echo $post_data;


curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  //CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POST => 1,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post_data,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "X-RapidAPI-Host: qrcode3.p.rapidapi.com",
        "X-RapidAPI-Key: somekey",
    "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=" . $delimiter,
    "Content-Length: " . strlen($post_data)

  ),

  
));


//
$response = curl_exec($curl);

$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
//echo "code: ${info['http_code']}";

//print_r($info['request_header']);

var_dump($response);
$err = curl_error($curl);

echo "error";
var_dump($err);
curl_close($curl);




function build_data_files($boundary, $postFields, $files){
    $data = '';
    $eol = "\r\n";

    $delimiter = '-------------' . $boundary;
    echo "This is the postFieldds data: <br><br>";
    foreach ($postFields as $name => $content) {
        $data .= "--" . $delimiter . $eol
            . 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="' . $name . "\"".$eol.$eol
            . $content . $eol;


        echo $data;
    }

    echo "This is the files data: <br><br>";
    foreach ($files as $name => $content) {
        $data .= "--" . $delimiter . $eol
            . 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="' . $name . '"; filename="' . $name . '"' . $eol
            //. 'Content-Type: image/png'.$eol
            . 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'.$eol
            ;

        $data .= $eol;
        $data .= $content . $eol;
        echo $data;

    }
    $data .= "--" . $delimiter . "--".$eol;


    return $data;
}
```

Do I need to do something like this to "GET" the image that was just uploaded or is there a way to capture that file information before the original POST is sent to the API?

```
// Get logo image id that was just posted: 

if (isset($response)) {
    $curlImage = curl_init();


    $result = json_decode($reponse, true);
    $imageId = $result["id"];


    
    curl_setopt_array($curlImage, [
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://qrcode3.p.rapidapi.com/images/$imageId",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            "X-RapidAPI-Host: qrcode3.p.rapidapi.com",
            "X-RapidAPI-Key: somekey"
        ],
    ]);
    
    $logoResponse = curl_exec($curlImage);
    $err = curl_error($curlImage);
    
    curl_close($curlImage);
    
    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo $logoResponse;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly:  You're going to have to find a way to store the original upload information so you can retrieve it later  --  beit in a `$_SESSION` variable or using `COOKIES`  etc etc ..

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).